# Optimizing a Query for splitting strings with a known size

Tags: sql-server, performance, functions, azure-sql-database, string, query-performance

I have a Column that has a . as a delimiter, it looks like so....

```
abc.efg.hij
```

I want a query that turns this into three columns, Col1, Col2, and Col3. I am wondering what the fastest way to do this is. So far I haven't been able to do very well with my limited database experience. I've got a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split](
   @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
 ) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
 AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @xml XML
   SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'

   INSERT INTO @t(val)
   SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
   FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
   RETURN
 END
```

This is how I'm doing it right now but I believe it could be made to go much faster, I'm also open to a significantly better function or outside the box ideas for splitting strings.I believe I'm running this `dbo.split(Name, '.')` three times and could only be running it once.

```
SELECT
      Col1 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.') WHERE Id = '1'),
      Col2 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.')  WHERE Id = '2'),
      Col3 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.')  WHERE Id = '3')
FROM Mains
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
SELECT
  Col1 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.') WHERE Id = '1'),
  Col2 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.')  WHERE Id = '2'),
  Col3 = (SELECT Val from dbo.split(Name, '.')  WHERE Id = '3')
FROM Mains
```

Use:

```
SELECT
  s.*
FROM Mains
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Val END) AS Col1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Val END) AS Col2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Val END) AS Col3
    FROM dbo.split(Name,'.') s
    ) s
```

The idea is that you still want exactly one row per row in Mains. And using an aggregate function inside `CROSS APPLY` will do just that. By using CASE you only need call `split()` once per row.

There are plenty of questions around here about splitting strings, and SQL DB does already have a `string_split()` function built in.

Answer (score 7):

As the delimiter is a dot a quite concise way of doing this would be

```
SELECT Col1 =  PARSENAME(name,3), 
       Col2 =  PARSENAME(name,2), 
       Col3 =  PARSENAME(name,1)
FROM Mains
```

The above does rely on none of the component parts being longer than 128 characters though as `PARSENAME` is intended for parsing dot delimited SQL Server object names and returns `NULL` if they won't fit into a `SYSNAME`

I haven't done any performance testing. I suspect the below may well perform better.

```
SELECT Col1 = LEFT(name, FirstDot - 1),
       Col2 = SUBSTRING(name, FirstDot + 1, SecondDot - FirstDot - 1),
       Col3 = SUBSTRING(name, 1 + SecondDot, 8000)
FROM   Mains
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.', name))) V1(FirstDot)
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.', name, 1 + FirstDot))) V2(SecondDot)
```